# Why is the clone step of a build from the Dockerfile not working and how can I fix it or find a workaround?

Tags: git, docker, openshift, dockerfile

I am getting the following error when building:

```
Cloning "https://code.myrepo.ch/scm/AM/my-web.app.git" ...
error: build error: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    pom.xml
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

As a work around I delete the following from the yaml :

```
  source:
    type: Git
    git:
      uri: 'https://code.myrepo.ch/scm/AM/my-web-app.git'
      ref: master
    contextDir: docker
    sourceSecret:
      name: scmsecret
```

and make this change:

```
source:
  type: Dockerfile
```

and then I add the contents of the dockerfile that was in the git repository using the openshift ui.

All of this works but the last line of the dockerfile does this:

```
CMD /usr/share/nginx/start.sh
```

And of course start.sh cannot be found.

How can I either solve the original problem (the problem with git) or embed start.sh somehow? I am olnly having this problem with master, in other words when using a branch.

Comment: Set the environment variable ``BUILD_LOGLEVEL=9`` on the build configuration so you can get more detailed logs. What OpenShift cluster is this? One you set up? Minishift? Or oc cluster up?

Comment: Can you provide the dockerfile?

Comment: What action do you do that causes the original error?

Comment: I changed the log level and now it works. This is probably a temp fix, I have seen this before when editting the yaml. Some fixes seem to cause the git clone to work. The dockerfile is irrelevant to the original problem, becuase this problem occurs before any of the dockerfile commands execute. This is a corporate openshift cluster.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve